# Проблема с методом .count()

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, методы

Есть допустим строка `turtle`, надо с помощью метода `.count()` узнать сколько раз входят все буквы в эту строку.

Например: `t:2, u :1, r:1, l:1, e:1`.

Не понимаю, как передать в `count` все значения `х`.

```py
def func_dict_from_x(x):
    s = x.count()
    return s
```

Comment: Сразу все значения - никак, только по одной, циклом. Или берите сразу класс Counter.

Answer (score 4):

1. Как вариант, можно так через dict comprehension:

```
def func_dict_from_x(x):
    return {letter: x.count(letter) for letter in set(x)}
```

2. Скорее всего, самым быстрым и разумным вариантом будет использовать Counter из стандартной библиотеки.

```
import collections


def func_dict_from_x(x):
    return collections.Counter(x)
```

Comment: `def dict_from_word(x):
    for letter in list(x):
        x.count(letter)
    return letter`


почему не работает,выдает только последную букву